# Nunit: Testing legacy code (private void) method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have been tasked with building unit tests for a bunch of legacy code. The specific task/goal for the below method is to test that the `messageProcessor.ProcessCustomerPhoneContactInfo(currentPhoneContact)` method is being called. I am also posting the test stub I have written so far but I would appreciate some direction because I think I am going down a rabbit hole here. How can I fill in the blanks on my test?

**Method being tested:**

```
private void logPhoneCallDialog_SaveContact(Contact currentPhoneContact)
    {           
        if (currentPhoneContact != null)
        {
            RefreshRenewalActivity();

            if (currentPhoneContact.TypeId == ResultType.TookAppointment)
        }

        NotifyServerOfActivity();

        ApplyAppointmentFilters();

        this.Activate();

        var messageProcessor = new MessageProcessor();
        messageProcessor.ProcessCustomerPhoneContactInfo(currentPhoneContact);
    }
```

**Test:**

```
[TestFixture, RequiresSTA]
class BucketBrowserTest
{
    [Test]
    public void logPhoneCallDialog_SaveContact()
    {
        //Arrange            

        //Act

        //Assert
    }
}
```

**Method that calls above method**

```
private void ShowPhoneCallLoggerDialog()
    {
        PhoneCallLoggerDialog dialog = new PhoneCallLoggerDialog(CurrentCustomer, CurrentBucket.BucketTypeId);
        dialog.Owner = this;
        dialog.SaveContact += new PhoneCallLoggerDialog.SaveContactHandler(logPhoneCallDialog_SaveContact);

        dialog.ShowDialog();
    }
```

**Event Handler for calling method**

```
public delegate void SaveContactHandler(PhoneContact currentPhoneContact);
    public event SaveContactHandler SaveContact;
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Is your test not working or are you looking for a better way to do it?

Comment: All I would like to test is whether or not the `ProcessCustomerPhoneContactInfo` method is being called.

Comment: I edited the OP to clarify the question better and eliminate my existing test code to not confuse anyone.

Comment: Do `RefreshRenewalActivity()`, `NotifyServerOfActivity()`, `ApplyAppointmentFilters()`, or `Activate()` have any side effects that prevent this from being unit tested? Secondly, can you post the method that calls this `private` one?

Comment: Also, is the `ProcessCustomerPhoneContactInfo()` method `virtual`, `abstract`, or defined on interface?

Comment: @DeanFriedland A method is intended to do a specific task/action. You can try to assert those task/action like (Database changes or file changes) to make sure that your method ProcessCustomerPhoneContactInfo is called.

Comment: @Praveen It is not a unit test then but an integration test.

Comment: @JohnH They do not have any side effects and yes I can post the calling method. Oh, and `ProcessCustomerPhoneContactInfo()` is a just a plain old public void method that I created.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, but that's only showing the event handler being hooked up. How is `Contact currentPhoneContact` being passed to that method? If we can add a parameter, we can potentially solve the problem.

Comment: @JohnH Sorry, I just added the event handler code to the OP. Not really well versed on events and delegates so I am not really sure how this is wired up. That code is actually in a separate class/file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the additional information you've supplied, I'm going to outline my assumptions before describing a possible solution:

1. You're able to safely construct an instance of this class, without calling anything out of process
2. Calling `logPhoneCallDialog_SaveContact()`, won't trigger side effects that prevent it from being tested

When refactoring legacy code, you often have to make design choices that you would normally avoid. This can include:

1. Testing implementation details
2. Making methods `public` or `internal`
3. Adding light abstractions that simply facilitate testing

In order to get a test around this, you're going to have to do at least one of those things.

Firstly, make `logPhoneCallDialog_SaveContact` `public`:

```
public void logPhoneCallDialog_SaveContact(Contact currentPhoneContact)
{
    // same body as before
}
```

Next, extract a method that holds the entire body of the first one, to end up with this:

```
public void logPhoneCallDialog_SaveContact(Contact currentPhoneContact)
{
    SaveContact(currentPhoneContact);
}

private void SaveContact(Contact currentPhoneContact)
{
    if (currentPhoneContact != null)
    {
        RefreshRenewalActivity();

        // This code from your example doesn't compile.
        if (currentPhoneContact.TypeId == ResultType.TookAppointment)
    }

    NotifyServerOfActivity();

    ApplyAppointmentFilters();

    this.Activate();

    var messageProcessor = new MessageProcessor();
    messageProcessor.ProcessCustomerPhoneContactInfo(currentPhoneContact);
}
```

Make the new method `public`:

```
public void SaveContact(Contact currentPhoneContact)
{
    // same body as before
}
```

If you haven't already, extract an interface for `MessageProcessor`:

```
public interface IMessageProcessor
{
    ProcessCustomerPhoneContactInfo(Contact currentPhoneContact);
}

public class MessageProcessor : IMessageProcessor
{
    public void ProcessCustomerPhoneContactInfo(Contact currentPhoneContact)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Now modify the methods like so:

```
public void logPhoneCallDialog_SaveContact(Contact currentPhoneContact)
{
    var messageProcessor = new MessageProcessor();
    SaveContact(currentPhoneContact, messageProcessor);
}

public void SaveContact(
    Contact currentPhoneContact,
    IMessageProcessor messageProcessor)
{
    if (currentPhoneContact != null)
    {
        RefreshRenewalActivity();

        if (currentPhoneContact.TypeId == ResultType.TookAppointment)
    }

    NotifyServerOfActivity();

    ApplyAppointmentFilters();

    this.Activate();

    messageProcessor.ProcessCustomerPhoneContactInfo(currentPhoneContact);
}
```

Now write your unit tests against `SaveContact`, mocking `IMessageProcessor`, instead of against `logPhoneCallDialog_SaveContact`.

## Edit

Here's an example, as requested. It's been a while since I've used `Moq` - which was in your original question - so the syntax may not be quite right, but something like this:

```
[Test]
public void SavesContact()
{
    // Arrange
    var contact = new Contact();
    var messageProcessor = new Mock<IMessageProcessor>();

    var subject = // whatever class contains the logPhoneCallDialog_SaveContact method          

    // Act
    subject.SaveContact(contact, messageProcessor.Object);

    // Assert
    messageProcessor.Verify(x => x.ProcessCustomerPhoneContactInfo(contact), Times.Once());
}
```

Also test the case where `contact` is `null`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time out answer this in such depth and explaining the the approach. I am excited to implement this because it is not intuitive by any stretch of the imagination. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Any chance you could tell me what my Arrange, Act, and Assert should look like?

Comment: @DeanFriedland I've added an example for you. You'll have to do the rest now. :)

Answer (score 0):

With the code as it stands, you cannot mock out the `messageProcessor`, but with a few changes, you could:

```
IMessageProcessorFactory _messageProcessorFactory;

public TheConstructor(IMessageProcessorFactory processorFactory)
{
    _messageProcessorFactory = processorFactory;
}

private void logPhoneCallDialog_SaveContact(Contact currentPhoneContact)
{           
    if (currentPhoneContact != null)
    {
        RefreshRenewalActivity();

        if (currentPhoneContact.TypeId == ResultType.TookAppointment)
    }

    NotifyServerOfActivity();

    ApplyAppointmentFilters();

    this.Activate();

    var messageProcessor = _messageProcessorFactory.Create();
    messageProcessor.ProcessCustomerPhoneContactInfo(currentPhoneContact);
}
```

Then you can Moq/Mock the interface and find out if the function was called.

Comment: Whilst your answer is absolutely true, as it's legacy code, changing the constructor may not be an option. We need more context from the OP.

Comment: At some point, if the code was not written to be testable, you have to change it to be able to test it.  Making 'minor' changes, such as my suggestion, are a first step towards getting the whole project tested.

Comment: "At some point, if the code was not written to be testable, you have to change it to be able to test it." We're in agreement there. The issue is that making a breaking change to a constructor in a monolith is not always a minor change.

Comment: Agreed.  Maybe the answer to the OP is to go back to whoever set the task and say "This code cannot be tested without being changed, either I make the required changes or I can't complete the task".

Comment: I am not able to modify the class constructor or any of the access modifiers :(

Comment: @DeanFriedland Then you aren't able to test the class.  To do X, you HAVE to do Y, you aren't allowed to do Y therefore you CAN'T do X.  I realise this might not be the answer you wanted, but sometimes the people assigning tasks don't understand the detail, like you do.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll bring up the issue with my supervisor then.